# Solve variable to expect a single duplicate

Tags: probability

I'd like some help solving the following problem.

X players each draw `1M` *distinct* numbers, each from their own, identical set of `2^75` possible numbers. In this experiment, there is a chance of two or more players drawing the same numbers. In order to have the expected number of such occurrences be equal to 1, what should be the value of X?

Next, the experiment is repeated `3.15E12` times. Summing the number of duplication cases (cases where two or more players drew the same number) of each experiment, in order to have the expected sum be equal to 1, what should be the value of X?

Comment: What have you tried?  The first part does not look difficult using linearity of expectation, and the second looks similar.

Comment: @Henry I _think_ that the second is a matter of summing the results of the first, but I'd like to be sure. The first is beyond my skill level, especially when it comes to how the multiple picks of one player interact with the multiple picks of multiple other players.

Comment: For the first, consider a particular value.  What is the probability it is chosen by $0$ out of $X$ people? What is the probability it is chosen by $1$ person?  What is the probability it is chosen by $2$ or more people? So in total, what is the expected number of values each chosen by $2$ or more people? What value of $X$ makes that $1$?  In some places you might want to use an approximation like $(1-\frac1n)^n \approx e^{-1}$